# How do I get hostname of iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, hostname

I'm not sure how to get the hostname of my iOS device? I'd like to compare NSNetServices against it, to ensure that it doesn't include its own hostname in the list of available services.

Comment: Please, please google these things.  The BSD header includes a function literally called `gethostname()`

Comment: @CodaFi why not supplying your comment as an answer - it seems complete, well researched ( :D ) and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<unistd.h>`, you can find the function `gethostname()` which takes an argument for a char pointer, and sadly enough, a length.  It null terminates if the second argument provided is too long (it defines `HOST_NAME_MAX` as 255, so that would be your best bet), so you can use some huge int value and still get a valid result.

Comment: Alright, this returned `andrews-macbook-air`, while the NSNetService had it set up as `Andrews-MacBook-Air.local.`. While I was able to easily append the `.local.`, I'm not sure how i would be able to get this in the correct case? This can't be done manually because macbook has a capital B, for example.